# Using diff function in R

Tags: r

My R codes are as follows:

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)

# Plot yrs vs total cases as time series
plot(data, xlab="Years", ylab="Total cases", type="o", col="blue", font.lab=2)

# Difference data to make data stationary on mean (remove trend)
plot(diff(as.numeric(data[1,])), ylab="First Difference", col="red", font.lab=2, type="o")
```

Running the 5th line of code gives only 1 point on the graph.

Why is that so?

Here is how my data look like:

[image: link].

Comment: `data[1,]` selects only the first row. You also have commas in your second column so `as.numeric` won't help. Also, please take a [tour] and read [ask] questions on SO.

Comment: Do you want `data[1,]` or eventually `data[,1]` ?

Comment: Is there any other alternative other than the    as.numeric    so as to calculate 1st difference on the whole lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load your data with custom `sep` and `dec` (or `read.csv2` for `;` separator and `,` for decimal points) from your data:

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=",")
# OR
data <- read.csv2(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
```

You can use names of the columns, instead of indexing. Then the second plot can be shown as:

```
plot(diff(as.numeric(data$Total.cases)), ylab="First Difference", col="red", font.lab=2, type="o")
```